# Unable to cretae fckeditor in zend form

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, ckeditor

I want to integrated fckeditor with my form I download ckeditor library from http://ckeditor.com/download

Everything works fine but its giving following error

ReferenceError:

**ReferenceError: CKeditor is not defined**

Following is the js code

```
   <script src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/js/fckeditor/fckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setUpFCK() {

            if (document.getElementById('body')) {
                var oFCKeditor = new CKeditor('body');
                oFCKeditor.BasePath = "http://localhost/ZendTecAdmin/js/fckeditor/";
                oFCKeditor.Height = 400;
                oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea();                    
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="setUpFCK()">
```

Answer (score 0):

1- try checking if the JS file is in "public/js" and it can be accessed, in this case:
localhost/js/fckeditor/fckeditor.js

2- you can use the ZF2 view helper to append the script file

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()
  // you can also use appendFile if the library has dependencies, that needed to be loaded first.
 ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/fckeditor/fckeditor.js');
?>
```

Update
1- Add a new script tag to attach the onload event handler to `window` not `body`, and remove the onload attribute.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        setUpFCK();
    }
</script>
```

2- or attache the onload event handler with the onload function, for example.

```
<script>
    function attachEvent(){
        window.onload = setUpFCK;
    }
</script>
<body onload="attachEvent()">
```

Comment: I am able to access localhost/js/fckeditor/fckeditor.js

Comment: I have updated the answer, the problem is with the onload function, it should be on `window` not `body`.